# What is ownProps in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am reading the [API on react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md) and looking at one of Redux' github examples: [Redux todo app](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos)

One of the containers, `FilterLink`, has `mapDispatchToProps` (and `mapStateToProps`) to accept two arguments, one of them being [ownprops](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos/src/containers/FilterLink.js).

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  onClick: () => {
    dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(ownProps.filter))
  }
})
```

The API docs says:

"If your mapStateToProps function is declared as taking two parameters, it will be called with the store state as the first parameter and the props passed to the connected component as the second parameter, and will also be re-invoked whenever the connected component receives new props as determined by shallow equality comparisons. (The second parameter is normally referred to as ownProps by convention.)"

I still can't fully grasp what it does. Can someone explain what `ownProps` does with a different example?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`ownProps` are the attributes that are passed when the component is used. In plain React these would be just called props.

for example in [Footer.js](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos/src/components/Footer.js) the FilterLink is used as:

```
<FilterLink filter="SHOW_ALL">
  All
</FilterLink>
```

So mapStateToProps method would be called with `ownProps` having the value:

```
{
  "filter": "SHOW_ALL",
  "children": ...
}
```

The `mapStateToProps` method is used in a Redux-wrapped component to combine the explicitly passed properties (`ownProps`) with the state handled by the Redux store into the `props` of the wrapped component.

So in your linked example of `FilterLink`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  active: ownProps.filter === state.visibilityFilter
})
```

the component is active (`this.props.active == true`) if the `filter` attribute (e.g. SHOW_ALL) matches the `visibiltyFilter` in `state`, i.e. if it is currently filtered by this value.

Comment: Is there anyway to access component state in `mapStateToProps`? Like `(state, ownProps, ownState)`. If not.. why not?

Comment: @EricGuan that's not possible and imho also not intended. From the component's perspective the props calculated in `mapStateToProps` are depending only on external things: either the attributes in the usage of the component (`ownProps`) or the global Redux `state`. The `mapStateToProps` is called whenever one of these changes. The internal `state` of a component can be handled completely inside the component itself without any support in this method.

Answer (score 0):

*ownProps* argument is simply **the props of the connected component**.
Here is a clear example...

*main.jsx:*

```
createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App something="maaaaagic" />
    </Provider>
)
```

*App.jsx:*

```
function App(props) {
  return (
    <>
      helleeeew
    </>
  )
}
export default connect((state, ownProps) => {
  console.log(ownProps.something) // *console:* maaaaagic
  return {}
})(App)
```